# Logic of code Guava's mightContain

Tags: java, operators, guava, bloom-filter

I was going through the code of Guava library, i was interested to understand the probabilistic match code of mightContain. could any one explain what they are doing in the code specially with the bit wise operator.
here is the code....

```
public <T> boolean mightContain(T object, Funnel<? super T> funnel,
        int numHashFunctions, BitArray bits) {
      long hash64 = Hashing.murmur3_128().newHasher().putObject(object, funnel).hash().asLong();
      int hash1 = (int) hash64;
      int hash2 = (int) (hash64 >>> 32);
      for (int i = 1; i <= numHashFunctions; i++) {
        int nextHash = hash1 + i * hash2;
        if (nextHash < 0) {
          nextHash = ~nextHash;
        }
        // up to here, the code is identical with the previous method
        if (!bits.get(nextHash % bits.size())) {
          return false;
        }
```

Comment: Which bitwise operator? There are two

Comment: i want to know why, with all of the operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is code from the `Bloomfilter` class, the logic goes like this:

Given the key, perform all of the chosen hashes on that key. Use each hash to pick a bit number and check if that bit is set. If any bits are not set in the filter at that position then this key cannot have been added.

If all of the bits are found to be set then we can only say that the filter **might** have had the key added. This is because it is possible for a different key (or a combination of a number of different keys) to result in all of the checked bits being set.

Note that the adding of a key to the filter does almost exactly the same function except that it **set**s all of the bits generated.

A [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom%5ffilter) object operates as follows.

1. A *number* of hash functions are chosen, each will calculate the location of a bit in the filter. (see [Optimal number of hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom%5ffilter#Optimal%5fnumber%5fof%5fhash%5ffunctions) for discussion on how many).
2. Hold an arbitrary length bit pattern - the length is unimportant but it should be *big enough* (see [Probability of false positives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom%5ffilter#Probability%5fof%5ffalse%5fpositives) for a discussion on what *big enough* means).
3. Each time a key is added to the filter, all configured hash functions are performed on the key resulting in a number of bits being set in the pattern.
4. To check if a key has already been added, perform all of the hash functions and check the bit found there. If any are found to be zero then this key **certainly has not been added to the filter**.
5. If all bits are found to be set then then it **may be** that this key has been added. You will need to perform further checks to confirm.

Comment: Yes this is from Bloomfilter  class. Could you explain it by a simple example, i am naive; about what are you talking about. :(

Comment: thanks :). one more question ;) do you know how to get the probabilistic match (an element or set of elements) from the set.

Comment: we can do using subsets from single set and checking it by mightContain. but any other more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two bitwise operators here: `>>>` and `~`.

The `>>>` is the "right shift, don't carry sign bit" operator. In Java, by default, if you shift:

```
1000 1100
```

right by 3 (using `>>`) you will obtain:

```
1111 0001
```

Using `>>>` which does not carry the sign bit you will get:

```
0001 0001
```

The second (`~`) is the bitwise negation, and is a simple way to obtain a positive number from a negative number, and it looks like they want positive numbers here (sparse array index maybe?). Applying this operator to:

```
1100 1010
```

which is a negative `byte` in Java will yield:

```
0011 0101
```

which is positive.

Basically, what this code does is create a hash of the object using a fast hash function, use that to circulate over a `BitArray` (no idea what that is -- an internal structure to `BloomFilter` probably), and ensure NON presence if at one point the hash is NOT present in the `BitArray`.

I suspect the `BitArray` is updated each time you add to the `BloomFilter` (using `.put()`, or `.putAll()`).